# Given an angle and opposite side in a triangle, find constraints on the side adjacent to the angle

Tags: trigonometry

> In triangle $ABC$, we are given an angle $A = 42°$, and its opposite side length, $a = 38$.

> i) For what values of adjacent side $b$ such that we
> have one unique triangle?

> ii) For what values $b$ do we have $2$ different triangles?

I was drawing a bunch of triangles with different cases where side $b$ varies, and came up with the following, but I'm not sure if this is correct and am wondering if someone more knowledgeable could verify, and/or correct my misunderstandings:

i) Here we can draw an altitude $h$ from $C$ meeting $AB$ at point $X$, making two triangles, $ACX$ and $BCX$. What I noticed is that if $a > b$, then we only get one unique triangle (since if we reflect $BCX$ across $h$, it lies beyond point $A$). Hence the constraint should be $\boldsymbol{b<38}$.

ii) Again if we draw the same altitude $h$ from $C$ meeting $AB$ at point $X$ to make two triangles $ACX$ and $BCX$, I notice that if $a < b$, then when reflecting $BCX$ across $h$, $BX$ will lie between $AX$, creating a second (smaller triangle) that fits the given criteria (however, if $a$ is too small compared to $b$, it will not make any triangle at all, i.e if $a < h$, then it won't reach $AB$). So a must be greater than $h$, but smaller than $b$, so,  $h < a < b$.  So now I express $h$ in terms of $b$ using right triangle $ACX$: $\sin(42°) = h/b \implies h = b\sin(42°)$. Since $h < a$, substituting we get $b\sin(42°) < 38 \implies b < 38/\sin(42°)$, giving $b < 56.79$ But since $a < b$, we have $b > 38$, so the constraint should be $\boldsymbol{38 < b < 56.79}$

Please let me know if any of this doesn't make sense, or I'm missing anything.

Comment: i get the maximum $b = 19/\sin 21^\circ = 53.016$ not the $56.79$ you got.

Comment: hmm, how did you get the numbers 19, and sin(21)?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is basically correct. I think it'd be easier to draw a circle with center in the vertex $C$ and fixed radius = **38** and look at its intersections with the ray $AB$ while the vertex $C$ is moving from the vertex $A$ into infinity.

Also please think about boundary cases - for example, the triangle with maximal $b$ will be unique again.

Answer (score 0):

> In triangle $ABC$, we are given an angle $A=42^\circ$, and its
> opposite side length, $a=38$.
>
> i) For what values of adjacent side b such that we have one unique
> triangle?
>
> ii) For what values b do we have 2 different triangles?

Also the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$ is fixed and known: $R=\tfrac{a}{2\sin\alpha}$.

[image]

The chord $BC$ splits the circumcircle into two arcs,
and the locus of the point $A$ is the upper (bigger) arc.
So, the length of the side $b$
must be can not be greater than
a diameter $2R$ of the circumcircle, $0<b\le2R$.

The point $A$ then can be found as the intersection point(s)
between the bigger arc of the circumcircle and the circle centered at $C$ with the radius $b$.

For $0<b< a$ and $b=2R$ there is just one intersection point, hence just one unique triangle
(assuming the non-degenerate triangles).

For $a<b<2R$ there are two intersection points, hence, two different triangles.

The case $b=a$ gives two intersection points,
but the second intersection point coincides with $B$,
so there is the different second triangle but it is degenerate.

Answer (score 0):

Locus of variable point A when  a, A are given is an arc of major segment of a circle of diameter which can be found from a right triangle.

$$ 2 R = \dfrac{a}{\sin A}= \dfrac{38}{\sin 42^{\circ}} \approx 56.58 $$

through A,B,C. Construction is made to find full geometry.

Intersection of two radii R to locate circle center ( circum-center) and *major segment locus* containing given angle A is indicated.

Sum of angle B and C is $ 180-42=138^{\circ}$

A graph is helpful to understand how sides are varying in length when A moves on arc.

Variable triangles form as C or B change when triangle sides b,c rotate along the arc locus with *maximum* value of (brown) hypotenuse length 2R $\approx 56.58$  from b,c can be calculated by Law of Sines for other sides:

$$ 2R=\dfrac{a}{\sin A }=\dfrac{b }{\sin B}=\dfrac{c}{\sin C}$$

There is a very small inaccuracy of angle A in the construction.

[image]

Please comment for any clarifications needed.